# AWS EMR sts assume-role call for transient cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-emr

On a transient AWS EMR Cluster using Steps, what is the best way to call `aws sts assume-role` ?

Should this be part of boot-strapping, or if the EC2 Instance Profile has been tailored with IAM roles etc. is this not in fact necessary? This is my guess from the docs on this last aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need not do this, it happens automatically if all attached to the EC2 Instance Profile Role for EMR.